# Minimum number of chessboard images for Stereo Calibration and Rectification

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

What is the minimum number of chessboard image pairs in order to mathematically calibrate and rectify two cameras ? One pair is considered as a single view of the chessboard by each camera, ending with a left and right image of the same scene. As far as I know we need just one pair for a stereo system, as the stereo calibration seeks the relations between the tow cameras.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stereo calibration seeks not only the rotation and translation between the two cameras, but also the intrinsic and distortion parameters of each camera. You need at least two images to calibrate each camera separately, just to get the intrinsics. If you have already calibrated each camera separately, then, yes, you can use a single pair of checkerboard images to get R and t. However, you will not get a very good accuracy.

As a rule of thumb, you need 10-20 image pairs. You need enough images to cover the field of view, and to have a good distribution of 3D orientations of the board.

To calibrate a stereo pair of cameras, you first calibrate the two cameras separately, and then you do another joint optimization of the parameters of both cameras plus the rotation and translation between them. So one pair of images will simply not work.

**Edit:**
The camera calibration algorithm used in OpenCV, Caltech Calibration Toolbox, and the [Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html) is based on the [work by Zhengyou Zhang](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/Papers/TR98-71.pdf). His paper explains it better than I ever could.

The crux of the issue here is that the points on the chessboard are co-planar, which is a degenerate configuration. You simply cannot solve for the intrinsics using just one view of a planar board. You need more than one view, with the board in different 3-D orientations. Views where the boards are in parallel planes do not add any information.

Comment: Few observation if I may. Intrinsic parameters are known to be 4 (fx, fy, cx, cy) and we also have 5 distortion parameters: three for radial (k1, k2, k3) distortion and two tangential (p1, p2). The space don't let me to elaborate them but the point is that the intrinsic parameters are tied to the 3D geometry of where the chessboard is in space; distortion parameters are tied to the 2D geometry of how the pattern of the geometry gets distorted, so we deal with these two classes separately ( we don't add all in the same equation system ). See next comment :)

Comment: One image with 3 corners give us 6 pieces of information can be used to solve both intrinsic and distortion. The only problem left is to deal with is extrinsic parameters. A view has 3 rotation parameters ( for each axis ) and 3 translation paramaters ( again for each axis ) which will add to a total of 6. This will be added up in the same equation system of the 4 intrinsic parameters giving us 10 total parameters to solve. Any view of chessboard cannot have more than 4 corners worth of information ( even if you provide more is pointless ) which give us 8 pieces of information.

Comment: So we miss two pices of information in one view to solve the entire 10 parameters system. BUT ALL I SPOKED SO FAR, was for one single camera calibration. When we have two, in our case we have because its stereo, the information doubles for each simultaneously snapshot. And STEREO calibration is different than ONE camera calibration. STEREO seeks the relation between cameras not their position in space. So my judgment says that one snapshot with both cameras is enough to stereo calibrate. A VERY IMPORTANT NOTE is that both camera must be exactly the same, of same type, which in my case are.

Comment: I still don't see why I would need more for a pure abstract mathematical solution where everything its perfect and unicorns are real :). Obviously, considering the noise and the numerical stability of the maths behind, we tend to take 10-20, even many more as you said to get good calibration results, but I'm asking if mathematically one snapshot with both cameras is enough for calibration.

Comment: "One image with 3 corners give us 6 pieces of information can be used to solve both intrinsic and distortion. "

Comment: @Chris, I have edited my answer. Please see the paper by Zhengyou Zhang for more information.

Comment: "Views where the boards are in parallel planes do not add any information". Maybe better said, "do not add any extra information". SO two planar views (as the case of a stereo snapshot) has same information as one view. That's the sparkle which elucidated the problem I guess. One thing to add ( although I haven't read the paper you provided, YET - I will ) is that because stereo calibration doesn't seek the relation of any of the camera in the real world but rather the relationship between them, we can assume any origin for our real world points.

Answer (score 0):

"One image with 3 corners give us 6 pieces of information can be used to solve both intrinsic and distortion. "

I think that this is your main error. These corners are not independent. A pattern with a 100x100 chessboard pattern does not provide more information than a 10x10 pattern in your perfect world as the points are on the same plane.

If you have a single view of a chessboard, a closer distance to the board can be compensated by the focus so that you are not (even in your perfect world) able to calibrate your camera's intrinsic AND extrinsic parameters.

Comment: If there is a problem with anything I said its not that sentence. I've read the book "Learning OpenCV": http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf
if you have a look at pages 387-388 there is the information I said in more detail. The problem is that everywhere I read I find all the theory for the single camera calibration, which are the pages mentioned as well, not for stereo.

Comment: As stated even in book, single camera calibration its different than stereo calibration. So the set of equations you are trying to solve are differently grouped stereo systems being able to give you more information with one snapshot ( its kinda obvious, you have two views of two identical cameras of the same scene and you are trying to find just the relations between them, ... yes yes, the intrinsic/distortion as well, but those are not a problem to be calculated in one view ).

Comment: And I never said you can get more information in one view than in another. One chessboard view can give you no more than 4 corners worth of information. As a 4 points is all we need to express a planar perspective. This is basically 8 parameters (x, y) pairs. even if you have 100x100 or 10x10 you get same maximum information, you are perfectly right, and I never said that its not true.

Comment: And If you cannot solve the stereo rectification with one snapshot from both cameras, ... why OpenCV dosen't restrict you regarding this input ? I've written a software in OpenCV an it seems I can calibrate ( very badly and I have to try 10 or more times to even get something which makes sens ) with only one snapshot. I was intrigued if the pure mathematical solution really lets you to do this as I am writing a detailed dissertation about my software.

Comment: add again, ... note the distinction between stereo calibration and single camera calibration.

Comment: You can get the relative pose from two cameras with two images of the checkerboard (1 per camera), but you will never be able to compute the intrinsic calibration (even without distortion) from just a single image.

Comment: Can you explain your reason ? :/ I just tryed to explain why you can. Intrinsic parameters are 4 (fx, fy, cx, cy). One image can give you more info to solve this system of equation.

Comment: If you have single view of the pattern, how can you tell if you are really far away from the pattern with a camera with a telephoto lens or if you are closer with a standard lens?

Comment: The idea is that we have some information about the calibration system. We speak about a chessboard which real word measurements are encoded in the algorithm which treys to solve this. You cannot give the train example :/

Comment: We have no information about the train and we will never be able to solve the train example you said. If we have knew the measurments of the train dore and a train windows ... we could solve the system ... 2 points, 4 parameters ... push them in the intrinsic system of equation ( which are also 4 )

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comment by accident. Even if you know exactly the size of your pattern, you can trade between distance and focal length. You have no way to distinguish them. Your equation has more than just four variables since you don't know the relative position between your camera and the pattern. With this, you suddenly have 10 (6dof for pose and 4 for your intrinsic calibration (no distortion)) parameters that you have to estimate.

Comment: Yes ... 10 parameters if you include the extrinsic as well. I was saying only about the intrinsic parameters. You are right. But this is again ... single camera calibration. What you have to say about stereo ... when we have two views of the same scene with two same cameras ... with such a pair can we stereo calibrate ? ... I mean just to find the relationship between cameras nothing else ( this is stereo calibration basically).

Comment: Where is your problem? You have 10 parameters to estimate and you say yourself that you get only 4 corners worth of information per view.

Comment: you can consider the stereo as taking one picture from a position ... then move your camera 10 cm to the left ... take another image. Only these two images ... will suffice for stereo calibration ? If not, ... hmm, not even humans with two eyes would be able to calibrate. Brain its not magic, its science :)

Comment: 4 corners of information is 8 pices of information ... left and right view of stereo will give us 16 in total ? Is it right to add them up like that ? This is basically my question. If Yes, you can stereo calibrate with one pair of left and right views of two cameras.

Comment: can you answer my last comment please ? :/ @FooBar